# Lazy evaluation and hidden environments in R

Tags: r

I have here a question about why I **don't** have a problem (it's a nice change of pace). Consider the following

```
MyFuncs <- (function(){

  hidden <- function(){return('ninja')}      
  foo <- function(){paste(hidden(), 'foo')}      
  bar <- function(){paste(hidden(), 'bar')}      
  return(list(foo = foo, bar = bar))

})()
```

So after sourcing this I have a list object that contains 2 custom functions, `foo` and `bar`. Both of these functions reference another function `hidden`, which is not part of that list. I cannot call `hidden`, yet `foo` and `bar` both work perfectly. Since R has lazy evaluation, I would have expected these to not work. `foo`'s definition references `hidden`, and when I try to evaluate `foo` I would expect it to throw an error because `hidden` cannot be evaluated.

```
> print(MyFuncs$foo())
[1] "ninja foo"
> print(MyFuncs$bar())
[1] "ninja bar"
> print(MyFuncs$hidden())
Error in print(MyFuncs$hidden()) : attempt to apply non-function
> foo2 <- function(){paste(hidden(), 'foo')}
> print(foo2())
Error in paste(hidden(), "foo") : could not find function "hidden"
```

As near as I can tell, the functions under `MyFuncs` are defined as being in their own environment, which is unnamed and not in the search path. Am I coming to one of the fin difference between an environment and a frame?

Comment: Lazy evaluation usually refers to function parameters. I'm not sure how to answer your question because i'm not exactly clear what it is. Where is the question mark here. Is it really about the differences between environments and frames? Or maybe you could reword the question to something that can be answered.

Comment: The objects that people call functions in R are really closures and carry with them pointers to the environment in which they were created, which in this case includes `hidden` for both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe I guessed right but can't explain this in the correct terms. Thanks for reading; I'll try to clean up the question tomorrow after I noodle it a bit more.

Comment: @42-: Do you have some reference I could read so that I can better understand the difference between a function and closure? That might help me clarify my question.

Comment: There are four instances of the word 'closure' in the R-FAQ and section "2.1.5 Function objects" of the R Language Reference (included with every distribution of R)  starts out by stating basically what I wrote above `In R functions are objects and can be manipulated in much the same way as any other object. Functions (or more precisely, function closures) have three basic components: a formal argument list, a body and an environment. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the environment of all internal functions is the local scope of `MyFuncs`:

```
MyFuncs <- (function(){

  hidden <- function(){return('ninja')}      
  foo <- function(){paste(hidden(), 'foo')}      
  bar <- function(){paste(hidden(), 'bar')}
  print(environment())   ## note I added this line
  return(list(foo = foo, bar = bar))

})()
```

Will print (in this case where I've run it):

```
<environment: 0x7fb74acd00d8>
```

Additionally:

```
> environment(MyFuncs$foo)

<environment: 0x7fb74acd00d8>

> environment(MyFuncs$bar)

<environment: 0x7fb74acd00d8>

> environment(get("hidden", environment(MyFuncs$foo)))

<environment: 0x7fb74acd00d8>

> get("hidden", environment(MyFuncs$foo))()

[1] "ninja"
```

`hidden` is not evaluated until called by `MyFuncs$foo()` in the first instance, but since everything is contained in that local function scope there's no reason it can't exist.

**Edit** I didn't address the lazy evaluation issue explicitly, but as @MrFlick says this is usually applied to function arguments unless you invoke `delayedAssign` explicitly. `hidden` is assigned, just not evaluated until it's called from `foo` or `bar`. The environment of the function `MyFuncs` is indeed "hidden" in the sense that it's not on the search path, but this can be changed.

We can create an object that represents this namespace:

```
> env <- environment(MyFuncs$foo)
> foo()
Error: could not find function "foo"
> get("foo", env)()
[1] "ninja foo"
```

We can attach it to the search() path:

```
> attach(env, name="Myfuncs.foo")
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv" "Myfuncs.foo" [...]
> foo()
[1] "ninja foo"
> hidden()
[1] "ninja"
```

And detach it using the name we assigned:

```
> detach("Myfuncs.foo")
```